# Change user name which I see in adb

Tags: adb, settings

```
 ./adb shell pm list users    
Users:
        UserInfo{0:*********:13} running
        UserInfo{999:XSpace:800010}

./adb shell dumpsys user
Users:
  UserInfo{0:*********:13} serialNo=0
    Created: <unknown>
    Last logged in: +39m10s436ms ago
  UserInfo{99:Airlock User:10000010} serialNo=1001
    Created: +386d6h17m29s394ms ago
    Last logged in: <unknown>
  UserInfo{999:XSpace:800010} serialNo=11
    Created: +540d9h24m8s349ms ago
    Last logged in: <unknown>
```

I would never set such a user name I've hidden behind the star symbols.

I couldn't find where it can be set in settings.

It's not a Wi-Fi AP SSID, not a bluetooth name, not a Lock Screen owner name.

How could that be? Even if someone took my phone, unlocked it with password, how they could do that? I'm puzzled.

Phone is Xiaomi Redmi 4 Pro with MIUI 9.

Comment: Did you cross-check that name with that reflected under Settings  -> Users? Alternatively,  in some devices the Contacts app permits setting up a Contact card which works as User name as well.

Comment: @Firelord I couldn't find neither Settings → Users nor this mystic username in my contact...